# How to access Couchbase RAW document with spring-boot-couchbase CrudRepository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am migrating an old application from using the Couchbase java client, 2.2.5 to Spring-boot-couchbase. I would like to use Spring Data's Crud Repository.

The problem I am running into is that the document in Couchbase is RAW format, (See more info here: [Couchbase non-json docs](https://docs.couchbase.com/c-sdk/current/nonjson.html)). I have set up a crud repository interface and when connecting to other buckets with other json-formatted data, it works perfectly. When attempting to read the byte array data I get this error:

`org.springframework.dao.DataRetrievalFailureException: Flags (0x802) indicate non-JSON document for id 9900fb3d-1edf-4428-b9e6-0ef6c3251c08, could not decode.; nested exception is com.couchbase.client.java.error.TranscodingException: Flags (0x802) indicate non-JSON document for id 9900fb3d-1edf-4428-b9e6-0ef6c3251c08, could not decode.`

I have tried the following object types in the repository:
`public interface MyRepository extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<Object, String> {`

- Object
- byte[]
- The object with an id and byte[] fields (and setters & getters)
- Objects from the java-client

  - CouchbaseDocument
  - RawJsonDocument
  - AbstractDocument
    I've also attempted to write a custom jackson mapper but the error message stays consistent in that it's trying to deserialize a non-json document.